# Confused about the output message (about signal handler and sigsuspend)

Tags: c, linux, signals

To better understand the concept of `sigsuspend`  I made two modifications as following, and got different output messages, which confused me.

> The code is from `csapp Chapter8 figure 8-42` about `sigsuspend`.

1. **Add line 10** `printf("Reap child %d\n", pid);`

```
   /* $begin sigsuspend */
   #include "csapp.h"
  
   volatile sig_atomic_t pid;
  
   void sigchld_handler(int s)
   {
       int olderrno = errno;
       pid = Waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);
       printf("Reap child %d\n", pid); //Line 10
       errno = olderrno;
  }
 
  void sigint_handler(int s)
  {
  }
 
  int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
      sigset_t mask, prev;
 
      Signal(SIGCHLD, sigchld_handler);
      Signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler);
      Sigemptyset(&mask);
      Sigaddset(&mask, SIGCHLD);
 
      while (1) {
          Sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &prev); /* Block SIGCHLD */
          if (Fork() == 0) /* Child */
              exit(0);
          /* Wait for SIGCHLD to be received */
          pid = 0;
          while (!pid)
              Sigsuspend(&prev);
 
          /* Optionally unblock SIGCHLD */
          Sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &prev, NULL);
 
          /* Do some work after receiving SIGCHLD */
          printf(".");
      }
      exit(0);
  }
  /* $end sigsuspend */
```

Use `kill -9 processID` to kill the process in another terminal, and got the following message, which confused me, why there was two `.` before each `Reap child` ?

```sh
Reap child 11880
..Reap child 11881
..Reap child 11882
..Reap child 11883
..Reap child 11884
..Reap child 11885
..Reap child 11886
..Reap child 11887
..Reap child 11888
..Reap child 11889
..Reap child 11890
..Reap child 11891
..Reap child 11892
..Reap child 11893
..Reap child 11894
..Reap child 11895
..Reap child 11896
..Reap child 11897
..Reap child 11898
..Reap child 11899
..Reap child 11900
Killed
```

Then, **Add line 30** `printf("Create child %d\n", getpid());`

```
   /* $begin sigsuspend */
   #include "csapp.h"
  
   volatile sig_atomic_t pid;
  
   void sigchld_handler(int s)
   {
       int olderrno = errno;
       pid = Waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);
      printf("Reap child %d\n", pid);
      errno = olderrno;
  }
 
  void sigint_handler(int s)
  {
  }
 
  int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
      sigset_t mask, prev;
 
      Signal(SIGCHLD, sigchld_handler);
      Signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler);
      Sigemptyset(&mask);
      Sigaddset(&mask, SIGCHLD);
 
      while (1) {
          Sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &prev); /* Block SIGCHLD */
          if (Fork() == 0) {/* Child */
              printf("Create child %d\n", getpid()); //Line 30
              exit(0);
          }
          /* Wait for SIGCHLD to be received */
          pid = 0;
          while (!pid)
              Sigsuspend(&prev);
 
          /* Optionally unblock SIGCHLD */
          Sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &prev, NULL);
 
          /* Do some work after receiving SIGCHLD */
          printf(".");
      }
      exit(0);
  }
  /* $end sigsuspend */
```

Use `kill -9 processID` to kill the process in another terminal, and got the message which exactly what I imaged.

```sh
Create child 15080
Reap child 15080
.Create child 15081
.Reap child 15081
.Create child 15082
.Reap child 15082
.Create child 15083
.Reap child 15083
.Create child 15084
.Reap child 15084
.Create child 15085
Killed
```

Why there could be such difference by only adding a `printf` line?

Comment: Please don't include line-numbers in the code you show. If we want to try the code for ourselves it makes it much harder to copy it. If you want to mark out specific lines, mention them in the question and then add comments on those lines.

Comment: @Some programmer dude: Thanks for the advice, I've edited the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the dots is a buffering issue.

When `stdout` is connected to an interactive terminal (i.e. a shell) the it's by default *line buffered*, meaning that the output is actually written (flushed) on newline.

Since you print

```
printf(".");
```

doesn't have a newline, it's save in the internal `stdout` buffer to be printed when you print a newline (like in the `sigchld_handler` function), a process exits or the buffer becomes full.

And now for the important part: This `stdout` buffer is inherited by the child process!

So when the child process exits it will flush the buffer and print one dot. And the signal handler will be invoked which print a newline which also flushes the buffer and prints one dot.

You could solve this by explicitly flushing the buffer after printing the dot:

```
printf(".");
fflush(stdout);
```

After doing this the buffer will be empty when the next child process is forked.

---

If you look closely in the "working" output, you still have the two dots, one printed by the child process before the "Create child" output, and the other in the parent before the "Reap child" output.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and quick answer！The idea `This stdout buffer is inherited by the child process` is exactly what I need.

Comment: A better solution is not to `exit` in the child as that could result in the parent's `atexit` handlers running twice. The suggested change only fixes this one particular `atexit` problem but still leaves the risk that there might be others.